# evaluate $f(z) $ described in the anticlockwise ( i.e. positive direction)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Evaluate   $$\int_{C} \frac{dz}{(z^2+ 4)^2}$$ where  $C = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z-i| = 2\}$ described  in the anticlockwise  ( i.e. positive direction)

My attempt: I used  Cauchy integral formula

$$\int_{C} \frac{dz}{(z^2+ 4)^2}=\int_{C} \frac{dz}{(z- 2i)^2(z+2i)^2 }=  -2\pi i \left.\frac2{(z+ 2i)^3}\right|_{z= 2i}=  \frac{\pi}{16}$$

is its  correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct. The only problem that I was able to detect was that, when you differentiated $\dfrac1{(z+2i)^2}$, you should have obtained $\dfrac{-2}{(z+2i)^3}$, but you seem to have missed that $2$.

Comment: ya...okss  i missed   @jose carlos sir   .. now   i got  $\pi /16$

Comment: I have edited your question. adding to it that correction.